# Android Studio Project Encoding Default Value

Tags: android, encoding, android-studio, ide

I'm using Android Studio 1.2, when I create a project, then I open the **File Encodings** setting window via **File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings**, there is the **Project Encoding** option which defaults to `GBK` on my computer (Windows 7 64 bit). I could manually change it to `UTF-8` for each project, but is there a way to let it default to `UTF-8` directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a try, it works for me.
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings, then find "File Encodings", change Project Encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Go through File -> Settings -> File Encodings in your Android Studio. See the attached screenshots.

Here, you have 4 options

1. Change project encoding to match UTF-8.
   [image]
2. Change IDE encoding to match other encoding.
   [image]
3. Change Default encoding for properties files.
   [image]
4. See the current encoding of your file at the bottom right corner of Android studio. You can also change it there.
   [image]

It will be helpful to you!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is I want to change the initial project encoding when I create a project (i.e., the default value of project encoding), which is `GBK` for now, and I want it to be `UTF-8`. To put it shortly, I ask this question to find a way to avoid going through the steps as you mentioned.

Comment: Android Studio configuration provides system default encoding as default if you want to UTF-8 then you have to change it manually for single project.

Comment: This is quite old question, but I am facing a strange problem. I have encoding problems but only in a library project. For example, if in a library project I assign "Código inválido" and I watch that variable, this is shown: "CÃ³digo invÃ¡lido". If I do that in the activity code, the variable is shown correctly. What's wrong with this?