# String type does not allow accented vowels

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have this assignment:

```
String msg = "El código QR ya no es válido";
```

when debugging, this is displayed:

`El cÃ³digo QR ya no es vÃ¡lido`

what may be the problem?

EDIT:

when that text comes from a Web Server, which sends texts using UTF-8 encoding, string is assigned correctly. The problem is only when assigning a string directly to a String variable.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Java compiler accepts a source code encoding attribute - make sure that's set correctly. If that's not it, then it's the encoding of whatever mechanism you're using to display the string.

Comment: The source file encoding in the text editor or IDE does not match the compiler encoding. What text editor / IDE are you using and how are you compiling the code?

Comment: @Joni It is an Android development. IDE is Android Studio and file is in UTF-8 enconding, I have just checked. Furthermore, the problem is only when assigning a String directly. When I retrieve a string from a call to a Web Service (which sends the text using UTF-8 format) it works.

Comment: This is an IDE or compiler configuration issue. There was a very similar question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580725/thai-script-seems-to-lose-utf-8-encoding-in-java-for-each-loop/63580816

Comment: You need to tell your compiler that the file is using the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Joni It is similar, but he started with an array of bytes. That could suggest I need to get a bytes array and then create a new string from it. It seems so tricky, doesn't it? I have never had this problem, neither with C# nor PHP. In this case of Java, file is already encoded as UTF-8. Will it also depends on how the compiler is configured? Anyway, I have forced compiler to be in UTF-8 but no solution.

Comment: @Joni I have found this with respect to IDE: `The encoding used to compile your project is specified in the build.gradle files. The default, which is used when no specific encoding is specified, is UTF-8`. So, I confirmed both file and compiler is in UTF-8. What else can I try?

Comment: I have found that this problem only exists for a class library project. If that assignment is made inside the Android activity, it works.